# Sql statement to prevent duplicates added to the database of a web site

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created this code in order to register users in my database. What I cannot manage to do, is to prevent adding the same user again and again. Here is my code:

```
connectDB();
$safe_fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['fullname']);
$safe_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email']);
$safe_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['pass']);
$addStatement="Insert into Users (Fullname,Email,Password,Is_Admin) values ('".$safe_fullname."','".$safe_email."','".$safe_password."','N')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$addStatement) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: How do you define "the same user"?  By their email address?  You can put a unique constraint on the table for that column.  Additionally you can perform a `SELECT` against the database to check for an existing value and, if one is found, present a friendly error message to the user.

Comment: I was trying to do the select method and find if the user already exists but I get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add unique to you table for (if it is meant to be unique) email or Username column:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE (Email);
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE (Username);
```

This way database only accepts one record with same email address or Username.

Other way to do this, is to select values from DB with given details. For example, let's use Email column:

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = '{$_POST['email']}'");
if(count($res) > 0) {
   //exists => do stuff
} else {
   //doesn't exist => do stuff
}
```

Comment: because you can't meet two different people with the same fullname, right?

Comment: @Alexander This is why he mentioned "if it is meant to be unique".

Comment: and with the same email

Comment: @OlafDietsche he haven't when I wrote the comment

Comment: I managed to make it work with your help and Im very thankfull! A last question: How can I make it pop up a message which will say "User exists"? because I tried it and it sends me in a blank page

Comment: Glad to help. I am sorry to say but giving you help for that "popup" thing is too hard without getting better look of your complete structure of code.